# Gradle build fails on android studio 1.2

Tags: android

I am trying to import some libraries, in Android Studio. I had the following error message: 
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0) is too low for project ':actionbarsherlock'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

So i installed Android SDK Build tools rev 19.1.0. I modified build.gradle file (app) looking like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.xx.xx"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.2"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
        compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
        compile project(':actionbarsherlock-fest')
        compile project(':actionbarsherlock-i18n')
    }
```

Also in Run/Debug Configurations, under App Engine DevAppServer, i set in App Engine SDK field the path for the new SDK, looks like that: C:\Users\cami\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0

So when i am trying to rebuild, i get exactly the same error message as before. Additionally, i had installed Android SDK Build tools rev 22.0.1, and i get warning saying update targetSdkVersion to 22.

Could please someone help me with this?

PS: Sorry for the very long post, and maybe for the many unnecessary details, but i am new in Android Dev.

Thank you

Comment: instead of giving sdk path as C:\Users\cami\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0
try giving
C:\Users\cami\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: Hi tnx for your help but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Please try my code from gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "esub.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0"
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help but unfortunately this is not working :( i still get exactly the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed all required SDK?
Please look at my Android SDK Manager:

[image]